# pgp using C# : Alternatives to Bouncy Castle

Tags: c#, pgp

I need to encrypt and sign data as well as decrypt and verify signature using PGP. Along with this, i also need to verify fingerprints programatically. I went through bouncy castle and the code is not as readable as i thought. Are there any easy (readable) alternatives to pgp for C# OR examples using bouncy castle that explain the code (to some extent)?

Comment: [SharpPrivacy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4284/SharpPrivacy-OpenPGP-for-C) perhaps?

Comment: Check our SecureBlackbox : http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pgp.php . Comes with samples, documentation and support.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Doesn't mean it doesn't work.

Comment: @Magnus I looked at it. Will probably go through their code again diligently. Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Sadly, secureBlackBox requires a license. I was looking for a free alternative.

Comment: You can also try DidiSoft OpenPGP Library for .NET https://www.didisoft.com/net-openpgp/